# What is this 2 player pegboard game?

Tags: identify-this-game

When I was young in the 1960s, a friend had the following game (my memory is rusty so take this description with a grain of salt).  It was a small square pegboard, with two sets of pegs (silver and gold), one for him and one for me. The interesting part: his job was defense (to protect the center) and my job was offense (to get to the center). I forget the moves, but somehow we could take each other's pegs until someone won. 
Can anyone identify this game?

Comment: This sounds something like Hnefatafl, but this is not the appropriate place for questions like this; I've moved the question to Board & Card Games Stack Exchange.

Comment: Or perhaps another in the TAFL family of games, like  [Alea Evangelii](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/33693/alea-evangelii).  you can see other TAFL games [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamefamily/4049/traditional-games-tafl/linkeditems/boardgamefamily)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's [Breakthru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakthru_(board_game)).

Breakthru is a modern game based on historic [Tafl games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tafl_games), released in 1965.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some more information about the game and why you think it was this?

Comment: I remember the defense pieces forming a circle around the center. Plus the game came out in the mid-60s which is when I played it.